# How To Show Each Element of a ArrayList<String> in a Tablecolumn in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

I have a `TableView<DataModelClass> table` which has only one `TableColumn name` in my `DataModelClass` there is a `ArrayList<String> nameList` that can contain one or **multiple** names. Now, when I run my code, the **Name** column looks like this, `[name1,name2,name3..]`but I want to show each of `name1` `name2` `name3` in a separate line. Like This,

```
-+-----------------+-                       -+-----------------+-
 |       Name      |   << I am Getting       |       Name      |
-+-----------------+-  Instade Like This >> -+-----------------+-      
 | [name1,name2,..]|                         |      name1      |   
-+-----------------+-                        |      name2      |
 |                 |                         |      name3      |
-+-----------------+-                       -+-----------------+-
                                             |                 |
                                            -+-----------------+-
```

I hope You Get the Idea, But How Can I achive That?

**Code Of DataModelClass**

```
public class DataModelClass {


    private ArrayList<String>nameList;

    private DataModelClass(ArrayList<String> nameList) {
        this.nameList = nameList;
    }

    public String getNameList() {
        return nameList;
    }

    public void setNameList(ArrayList<String> nameList) {
        this.nameList = nameList;
    }
}
```

**Code of TableVied**

```
private TableView<DataModelClass> table = new TableView<DataModelClass>();
TableColumn colName = new TableColumn("Name");
        colName.setMinWidth(80);
        colName.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<GroupDataForTable, ArrayList<String> >("nameList"));

private ObservableList<DataModelClass> groupData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
groupData.add(new DataModelClass(someNonEmptyArrayList));
table.setItems(groupData);
```

Comment: The type you specify for the `TableView` (`DataModelClass` in your case) is supposed to be the type of the object represented by *each row of the table*. Do you have a whole list of `DataModelClass` objects, or only one?

Comment: @James_D For the Question I asked, Please Ignore The nameX at this moment. I've edited my question accordingly. Thank You.

Comment: Can you answer the question I asked in the comment?

Comment: @James_D I have Only One object of `DataModelClass` which is `groupData` in this object I have an `ArrayList<String> nameList` which list contains 3 Strings `name1` `name2` and `name3` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Although your design is kinda weird, yet..*

You can use streams and convert your list to a String object and return it from the getter method.

```
nameList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

This will give you each element in a newline, yet it is one complete String.

```
public class DataModelClass {

    private List<String> nameList;

    ...

    public String getNameList() {
        return nameList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    }

    ...
}
```

In your class, where you are using TableView,

```
TableColumn<DataModelClass, String> name = new TableColumn<DataModelClass, String>("Name");
name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<DataModelClass, String>("nameList"));
```

Comment: This will display all the values in a single table cell. Why use a table at all in this case?

Comment: @James_D I represented the problem this way, so that readers do not get a hard time reading my code. In reality, I have a `TableView` consisting 7 Columns and many rows, which serves all my purpose except the problem I mentioned above.

Comment: @James_D Though you are right, but this is what the OP asked in the question. I am not sure why he wants it. @Desh_Er_Bojha If you do not have an `ObservableList<DataModelClass>`(as mentioned in your comments), then James_D is right and you must think of some other control other than TableView.

Comment: @Desh_Er_Bojha But if you set it up this way, your table has only one row (not "many rows" as you state). Again (not sure I can make this any clearer), if you have a `TableView<DataModelClass>`, then there is only one row for each instance of `DataModelClass`. So if you only have one `DataModelClass` instance, then your table only has one row (no matter how that row is displayed).

Comment: @James_D I guess he has a List of `DataModelClass`, which in turn has another `List of names` and he wants each of these names(from the list) to be represented in one cell.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha No, he states in the comments "I have Only One object of `DataModelClass`"

Answer (score 0):

The type you specify for the `TableView` is the type of the object represented by **each row of the table**. Since you only have a single object of `DataModelClass`, that is not the correct type to use for your table view.

As your question stands, each row contains only a string, so you should have

```
private TableView<String> table = new TableView<String>();
```

and then you can fill the items from your `DataModelClass` instance simply by

```
DataModelClass data = new DataModelClass(someNonEmptyArrayList);
table.getItems().setAll(data.getNameList());
```

Now you just need to make sure the column displays the correct value:

```
TableColumn colName = new TableColumn("Name");
colName.setMinWidth(80);
colName.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue()));
table.getColumns().add(colName);
```